# Determining the currently selected TabBarItem from within a tableViewController on the iPhone?

Tags: uitabbarcontroller, ios

I have 2 tabs in my TabBar.  They both hold instances of the same `UITableViewController`.

The hierarchy goes

`UITabbarController > UINavigationController > UITableViewController`

From within the tableViewController I'd like to determine which tab is currently selected.  I know I can use the `selectedIndex` property of the `UITabBarController` I just don't know the easiest way to refer to if from within the current `viewController`.  Do I walk up through the superviews of each view to find the `TabBarController`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you instantiate and store the *UITabBarController* in your App Delegate, you can expose it as a property of that object. You can store a static global pointer to your App Delegate object and expose it through a class method:

```
+ (MyAppDelegate*) instance
{
    return g_Instance;
}
```

When you need your tabBarController you can use:

```
[MyAppDelegate instance].tabBarController
```